# keep button drawable image dimensions as original

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-imagebutton, google-books

I created an app where I use Google Books API in it.

As part of the attributions they require, I need to add to each query results the following [button](https://www.google.com/intl/en/googlebooks/images/gbs_preview_button1.png):

[image]

Now, I wanted to use that Image as a background to a button but I got this results:

[image]

As you can see it seems to be stretched with bad quality.

The xml I used is:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/tv_Link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imagecard"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagecard"
    android:background="@drawable/gbs_preview_button"
    android:elevation="50dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/assistant_semibold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorLightPurple"
    android:textSize="8sp" />
```

In order to fix it, I decided to use bitmap:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/gbs_preview_button"
    android:tileMode="disabled"/>
```

The problem is that it became small like this (good quality, but small):

[image]

This dimension is too small since they require the height to be 24dp.

Is there any way I can add this image to the button, to make it 24dp height and still to keep the quality of the image?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to hardcode the height to `24dp`, then you can also hardcode the width to a value that keeps the aspect ratio of the original image size which is (88 x 31).

So, set the width to `68dp` instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: I still seems to lower the quality of the image but I guess it is still better compared to earlier.

Comment: if you would get a higher quality image than this, it can be better

Comment: All I could find is their official link to this image which is 88x31 as you said.